# JQuery not working properly in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am currently developing an ASP.NET webpage and I have run into the most irritating problem I have ever encountered.

I have been researching this problem for the past three days, and cannot find anybody who has even had this problem, let alone any solutions.

I have created a menu/submenu with HTML/CSS, and I am adding some kind of toggling effect to the submenu to make it either slide down or fade in (I've tried both, and both yield the same result).

In Internet Explorer, it works great. I can hover over the menu, it'll slide down or fade in correctly, then when I move the mouse away it'll disappear.

In Chrome/Firefox, I'm not so lucky. The submenu starts out hidden, then if I hover over it once, it will appear. If I move the mouse away, it instantly closes and then re-opens on its own. At this point, it's beyond return. If I hover over it, it disappears, and if I move the mouse away again, it'll re-appear. This will continue to happen until the page reloads.

Here is the menu in HTML...

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services.aspx">Services</a>
            <ul id="submenu">
                <li>Custom CRM</li>
                <li>Website Development</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

As for the CSS pertaining to this menu, this is it...

```
#menu
{
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li 
{
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;   
    width: 25%;
    font-size: larger;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;

}

#menu li a 
{
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;

}

#menu li:hover 
{
    background-color: #4CC417;
}



#menu li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
}

#menu ul 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 36px;
  width: 140%;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  left: 0;
}

#menu ul li 
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: medium;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    background-color: #387C44;
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;

}

#submenu ul 
{
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;

}

#submenu 
{
    display: none;
}
```

And finally, here is the JQuery code I created for this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menu ul").parent().hover(function () {
            $("#submenu").stop(true, true).fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

--Mark

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, `hover` accepts two function parameters (one for mouseover and one for mouseout). Second, I'm going to recommend using `on`:

```
$('#menu > li').on({
  mouseover: function() {              
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown(300);
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).hide();
  }
});
```

Through jQuery's checks and balances, it will return if the `li` has no child `ul`.

Comment: I don't need to try this to know that this will fill up the queue with chained effects

Comment: It will, and you can add a `stop`. I just wanted to illustrate how it would work.

Comment: It works better, but the only problem I'm finding is that if I'm using mouseover and mouseout, technically, there is a mouseout event when I leave that parent menu item while trying to go down to a submenu item. Any ideas on how I could make it stay if I move on to a submenu item?

Comment: Ah, you would attach the events to the `li` instead of the `#submenu`. Change `#menu ul < li` to `display: block` and the child `ul` to `width: auto; height: auto;`. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Are you sure? I appreciate this help, trust me. But I'm still having trouble. I made the change above but now it isn't making the effect at all, as if it's checking the wrong item.

Comment: Because my answer is wrong. I'm sorry, rough day. It's going to fire the event as you hover over *any* of the list items. Let's try this again.

Comment: That's interesting, but now every menu item causes the submenu to appear, rather than only the one that has children.. and it still kinda flickers when going between the submenu items as if it's fading out and fading back in quickly.

Comment: Without the "children" operator for (#menu > li), I just tried using (#menu li) and it doesn't fade out and then fade back in when going through menu items. Rather, it flickers for a second but it's hardly noticeable.  Same problem as I mentioned above though. All #menu li items make the one submenu appear.

Comment: I keep updating my answer. The `if` statement should evaluate to `false` for every other `li` element and `true` for the `li` which contains the `ul#submenu`.

Comment: I know I keep refreshing and trying what you update. I agree, it should evaluate that way but for some reason it is not.

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu > li').on({
                mouseover: function() {
                    if ($(this).children('ul')) $("#submenu").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
                },
                mouseout: function() {
                    if ($(this).children("ul")) $('#submenu').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });
        
    </script>

Comment: I'm sorry, Mark. I really rushed this one. One issue with yours is the boolean parameters that `stop` accepts. The first one clears the queue if `true` and the second one jumps to the end of the animation if `true`. Try `stop(true, false)` and use my updated answer. This seemed like such a simple problem to solve for, but for some reason my brain is not grasping it!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9LEMZ/3/

Is this what your after? (If not please feel free to direct me further!)

I've changed the jquery completely to fade in the sub elements, initially hiding the submenu. Also removed the display:none from the css to aid in this (as its now hidden through .hide() )

Cheers,

Comment: Very nice. Very close. In Chrome, however, it works the first time, but then when you mouse out, it doesn't do the effect anymore whether you go in or out. 

Furthermore, in Internet Explorer, if you mouseout and it starts to fade out, then mouse back in, it'll freeze in a half-faded state instead of fading in more. Not sure why...

Thanks so much !

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling Chrome might be the same as above. Just tested what you said and if you give it a 5 seconds or so it does start working again. I think its to do with the slow time of the fadeout(). For example here http://jsfiddle.net/9LEMZ/4/ I've changed it to show() and hide() and it seems to be ok! @Mark

Comment: Alternatively you can add a time ~50-75 rather than using "slow" for the time e.g. .fadein(50) and .fadeout(50)